# Missing operands - rm command

Tags: bash, rm

In the below code,

```
#!/bin/bash

sDir=/a/b/c
dDir=/d/e/f
rDir="$dDir/recent"

shopt -s nullglob
:    
rm $rDir/$deviceName*
:
```

---

problem line  `rm $rDir/$deviceName*` shows missing operands without echo command

```
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Have you tried to debug this? What have you find until now? This depends on the files you have got on disk.

Comment: Show us the __exact__ and __complete__ error message that you see. Don't remove parts of the error message because you think they are unimportant. Let us judge what parts are important.  Also, you have included some `echo` commands useful for debugging.  Show us the script's output so that we can see what those commands print.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro If it depends on files, then it should give `rm $file_prefix*
rm: cannot remove 'xx-yy-zz*': No such file or directory`

Comment: The exact error message is: "invalid operands" ?  Not "missing operand" or "invalid option"?

Comment: Oooh, `shopt -s nullglob`, eh?

Comment: @overexchange The current version of the question does contain the relevant part of the code and also the complete error message: Very good!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have `shopt -s nullglob`, the command `rm $rDir/$deviceName*` expands to just `rm` when the glob pattern matches
nothing.

Indeed, calling `rm` with no parameters results in the message you saw:

```
$ rm
rm: missing operand
Try `rm --help' for more information.
```

Contrast these two:

```
$ rm nonexistent*
rm: cannot remove `nonexistent*': No such file or directory

$ (shopt -s nullglob; rm nonexistent*)
rm: missing operand
Try `rm --help' for more information.
```

One simple, unsafe, way to silence errors from `rm` on missing parameters would be to call it as `rm -f`.

Note that it would probably be much better, instead, to avoid ending up in a situation where `rm` is called with a parameter made from unset variables in the first place: `set -o nounset` will forbid using unset variables (but will do nothing to variables set to the empty string), for example; if you were to do `rm $x/$y*` with both variables unset or empty, the parameter would become `/*`, meaning all files directly in the root directory.

Comment: How to overcome this error

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion at the end of the answer?

Comment: @roaima: Of course. Perhaps I should make this more explicit.